# Interpolate hourly data based on time frequency of data from other source

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, missing-data

I am looking for suggestion to interpolate available data with hourly frequency   based on time frequency of other data source.

For example:

I have one data frame containing weather measurements with hourly frequency as mentioned below, and sensor readings with interval of 4 to 5 minute approx. So, i want convert my weather measurements based on the time frequency of sensor reading from other data source.

could pandas be used for this purpose , instead of pyspark ? i know there are some features there. Thank you
Weather measurement:

```
+----------+----------------------+
|Wind_speed|Forecast_Time         |
+----------+----------------------+
|22        |2019-01-29T15:00:00+00|
|17        |2019-01-29T16:00:00+00|
|23        |2019-01-29T17:00:00+00|
|11        |2019-01-29T18:00:00+00|
|10        |2019-01-29T19:00:00+00|
+----------+----------------------+
```

Sensor readings:

```
+----------------------+-----------+------+
|DateTime              |Total count|Avail |
+----------------------+-----------+------+
|2019-01-29T15:24:02+00|45         |350   |
|2019-01-29T15:20:19+00|511        |710   |
|2019-01-29T15:24:02+00|131        |352   |
|2019-01-29T15:24:02+00|134        |376   |
|2019-01-29T15:24:02+00|69         |436   |
|2019-01-29T15:20:24+00|472        |935   |
|2019-01-29T15:24:06+00|138        |330   |
|2019-01-29T15:24:06+00|415        |749   |
|2019-01-29T15:29:02+00|45         |350   |
|2019-01-29T15:20:19+00|511        |710   |
+----------------------+-----------+------+
```

Results could be somehow like this:

```
+----------+----------------------+
|Wind_speed|Forecast_Time         |
+----------+----------------------+
|22        |2019-01-29T15:24:02+00|
|17        |2019-01-29T15:20:01+00|
|17        |2019-01-29T15:24:00+00|
|11        |2019-01-29T15:29:06+00|
|10        |2019-01-29T15:20:00+00|
+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: if you know how to do it in pandas, then just create the function and use a [pandas_udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf)

Comment: Thanks @Steven. I tried it and results are kind of weird. because too much null values. any suggestion, and i wonder why somebody disliked the post

Comment: if you could show us what you did, that'd be a good start. Just like this, we can't really help you !

Comment: @Steven Thank you for your support. experiment was successful, only thing i was missing was to sort before interpolation and afterwards it worked fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know how to do it in pandas, then just create the function and use a pandas_udf